# Error using \newcommand within a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, macros

For some reason my [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation does not compile when `\newcommand` is placed inside the `frame` environment. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First slide}
  \newcommand{\asdf}[1]{What is the #1 problem?}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.

Note that the `\asdf` macro is not even used after it is defined. Strangely, when I place the definition outside of the `frame` environment, everything works fine. What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Put the definition outside of the frame.

Comment: Put definitions into the preamble!

Comment: That's what I did when I realized that this is what was causing my presentation not to compile.  I just wonder why is it the case and whether it should be considered as a bug in beamer.

Comment: For what it's worth - this doesn't cause an issue if the newcommand has no optional arguments.  (as for putting the definition into the preamble - this makes it hard to use particular graphics repeatedly in different presentations - each time you have to hunt through the preamble to get the relevant commands).  I'm putting the commands right before `\begin{frame}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `fragile` should solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{First slide}
  \newcommand{\asdf}[1]{What is the #1 problem?}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since when can't you use overlays when the frame is fragile?

Comment: Pity that this behavior is not documented in the beamer manual.